# Custom Accordion Toggle one Item at a Time in Vue

Tags: html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js, accordion

I am using Vue with Nuxt 2 and having Problem in my Custom Accordion component.

i want to toggle one accordion at a time. But what actually happening is that if i click on first accordion Link, the body of first Link(accordion) is opening. And without closing the first one, if i open on second link(accordion), the second accordion body also opening. Which i want to avoid. If i wanna open other accordion, the opened ones should first close. So how do i achieve this in vue way, without using any library.

**Accordion Toggling Process:**
I am using **ACTIVE** value to toggle the accordion by adding **aria-expended = "true"** on my anchor Tag whenever it get clicked. At the same time i am showing or hiding the **accordion-item-body** based on **ACTIVE** value.

**My component Accordion:**

```
<template>
  <div id="accordion" ref="accordion" class="accordion">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue"
import { props } from "./props"

export default Vue.extend({
  name: "Accordion",
  props,
  created() {
    this.$nuxt.$off("eventName")
    this.$nuxt.$on("eventName", ($event: any) => this.toggleActive($event))
  },
  methods: {
    toggleActive(e: any) {
      console.log(e)
    },
  },
})
</script>
```

**My AccordionItem component:**

```
<template>
  <div class="accordion-item" role="tab">
    <div class="accordion-item-header">
      <a
        :aria-expanded="active"
        @click.prevent=";(active = !active), $nuxt.$emit('eventName', active)"
      >
        {{ title }}

        <span
          class="material-icons"
        >
          expand_more
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <transition name="accordion">
      <div v-show="active" class="accordion-item-body" role="tabpanel">
        <slot />
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue"
export default Vue.extend({
  name: "AccordionItem",
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      active: false,
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

**Usage of Accordion and AccordionItem in Parent:**

```html
<Accordion :items="items">
  <AccordionItem
    v-for="item in items"
    :id="item.id"
    :key="item.id"
    :title="item.title"
  >
    <div v-html="item.description"></div>
  </AccordionItem>
</Accordion>
```

Comment: I want something like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4g5QWu9rfA

But with some adjustments in my code.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have `$nuxt.$emit` and `this.$nuxt.$on`. What does it bring to the table? At the end, the tutorial is showing you how to achieve that: by checking the actual selected index (there is only one at a time), hence the selected should keep the given accordion open while the others are closed.

Comment: $nuxt.$emit and this.$nuxt.$on were there just for testing purpose.
Because i am trying to solve the problem on my own. But it didn't went well.

Can you please show how can i make my code working like i explained above?

Comment: Mainly as in the tutorial, pass the `index` (to the component as a prop) and make a condition regarding this exact number in your `v-show`.

Comment: The Problem is, my accordion structure is bit different.
I am passing index value from the <AccordionItem
            v-for="(item, index) in benefits.items"
            :id="item.id"
            :key="item.id"
            :title="item.title[$i18n.locale]"
            :index="index"
          > and created a prop in AccordingItem but it's not getting the index value.

Comment: Any error? What do you see in the Vue devtools so far?

Comment: Can you please explain this here in this chat ?
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244293/discussion-between-dnd2k21-and-kissu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple yet working solution (I didn't implemented the styling of course, but the functionality is working fine).

For the wrapper

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <accordion
      v-for="(item, index) in list"
      :key="item.id"
      :item="item"
      :active-index="currentlyActiveIndex"
      :item-index="index"
      @update:itemIndex="currentlyActiveIndex = $event"
    ></accordion>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'AccordionList',
  data() {
    return {
      list: [
        { id: 1, name: 'hello' },
        { id: 2, name: 'world' },
        { id: 3, name: 'swag' },
      ],
      currentlyActiveIndex: null,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

`Accordion.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="updateIndex">get this index: {{ itemIndex }}</button>
    <span v-show="activeIndex === itemIndex">{{ item.name }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Accordion',
  props: {
    item: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {},
    },
    activeIndex: {
      type: Number,
      default: null,
    },
    itemIndex: {
      type: Number,
      default: null,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    updateIndex() {
      console.log('index updated:', this.itemIndex)
      this.$emit('update:itemIndex', this.itemIndex)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

---

This could also be achieved with something like `{ id: 1, name: 'hello', isActive: false }`, a bit cleaner but both methods are valid here.

PS: I don't know how to use TS neither, but I'm sure you can figure this part yourself (not the blocker here I guess).

Comment: But this is not exactly how i wanted it to be.
this is completely different code.

why i cannot go with this method is because i am using my component in many other components too, which i cannot change.

I want something working with my own code.

Accordion, AccordionItem and Usage of both in Parent .

Comment: @DnD2k21 the names are different but you can totally rename my snippet here, the functionality will be the same. It's not like there is a big difference anyway.

Comment: Those are TS errors, not sure how to fix those I have to admit. But this is unrelated to Vue itself. Sorry if I cannot help more on this aspect. You could ignore it if it's not critical.

Comment: Just one problem, i cannot close the opened accordion.
Like if i clicked on first index.
and re-clicked on it. It should close. But it's not closing/collapsing.

Comment: @DnD2k21 you could apply a condition when clicking: "if clicked on an index that is already active, set the state to `null`", that way it will close if already open.

Comment: Am i doing it wrong?

activeIndex === itemIndex ? updateIndex : null

Comment: This is not possible because activeIndex is a prop..

@click.prevent="
          activeIndex === itemIndex ? (activeIndex = null) : updateIndex
        "

Comment: Please update your Post with this. Thanks.


<accordion
      v-for="(item, index) in list"
      :key="item.id"
      :item="item"
      :active-index="
              currentlyActiveIndex === index
                ? (index = null)
                : currentlyActiveIndex
            "
      :item-index="index"
      @update:itemIndex="currentlyActiveIndex = $event"
    ></accordion>